# How to deploy application that uses Intel IPP?

Tags: linux, intel-ipp

I write a program in Linux for convert sound. I use Intel IPP (Integrated Performance Primitives) libs. I have added ipps and ippcore libraries:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64/ -lipps
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64/ -lippcore
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64
```

My program run correctly in Qt Creator, but executable file doesn't run.
I have added all Intel IPP libraries to the folder contains executable file.
Output of command ldd -r:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1e9fe000)
libjack.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 (0x00007f577a9cf000)
libipps.so.8.2 => not found

...
...

undefined symbol: ippsMalloc_64f    
undefined symbol: ippsFIRInit64f_32f    
undefined symbol: ippsFIR64f_32f    
undefined symbol: ippsMalloc_32f    
undefined symbol: ippsFIRGetStateSize_64f   
undefined symbol: ippsMalloc_8u (./jk)
undefined symbol: ippsFIRGenBandpass_64f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

- carry IPP dynamic libs with application executable file (use **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to specify folder location of IPP dynamic libraries), or
- build your application with static IPP libraries (specify library files as object files: **...** **$IPPROOT/lib/intel64/libipps.a** **$IPPROOT/lib/intel64/libippcore.a** and so on in command line to the linker).